# Grouping multiple button properties

Tags: c#

am quite new to C# so sorry if the question is simple or I'm missing something.

I am wanting to group a bunch of button properties (the Button.Text properties) because I have a large number of buttons and want to add an if statement to all buttons.
(example: If text = message 1, then Button.Color = red)

Because I have so many buttons, just wondering if grouping the text properties is possible, so I only have to write the if statement once instead of for each button.

Below code is just an example of ONE of the many buttons and what properties I want changed if the text of the button is Available...

```
{
        using (var form = new Classroom())
        {
            form.ShowDialog();
            b1111.BackColor = Color.Red;
            b1111.Enabled = false;
            b1111.Text = form.SelectedTemp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not write a method which you pass the textbox object to? If your method was called `DoTheThing`, you could then simply call `DoTheThing(textBox1); DoTheThing(textBox2);` etc.

Comment: You talk about an `if` statement in your question but show no such thing in your code.  It helps if the code relates to what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Grouping the text properties" doesn't sound like a description of what you want to do.  You're talking about doing the same thing for a number of items and that's exactly what a `foreach` loop is for:

```
foreach (Button btn in myButtonList)
{
    if (btn.Text == someText)
    {
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

The real question is how you create the list.  You can do it explicitly:

```
var myButtonList = new[] {Button1, Button2, Button3};
```

or you can get all the `Buttons` in a particular container:

```
var myButtonList = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

If you only want some of the `Buttons` in a container then you can filter the list if there is some common trait that identifies them, e.g.

```
var myButtonList = Controls.OfType<Button>()
                           .Where(btn => btn.Name.StartsWith("btn"))
                           .ToArray();
```